# how to get back files that git removed from local directory

Tags: git, github, gitlab

i had cloned angular-electron from it's github repository and worked on it for nearly 6 months. i had an application ready for deployment.

I wanted to upload my directory to my newly created gitlab repository.
it seems that angular-electron is cloned again and all my files are gone.

i have tried git log and git reflog to revert to former HEADs but it only shows mt the latest changes.

Comment: how/where did you add the new repository in your existing code?

Comment: @oznog i didn't add it. i wrongly cloned angular-electron again and it deleted all my files

Comment: when you say you cloned it again, you mean that you overwrote the former clone?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to a previouse commit state you need to use the git checkout command.
E.g. if you want to get back to the last commit you can use git checkout HEAD^.

If you want to checkout a specific commit first run a git log and find the commit you want to checkout (by it's commit hash). Then use git checkout  to checkout this state.

Git can't really delete all your files without giving many warnings. Your work will still be in the history. (Maybe it's easyer to help you when you could post the git log and what state you want to checkout)

Answer (score 0):

using below command did the trick for me and brought my files back:

```
git reset --hard refs/heads/master
```